# oracle how to get intersect of this two

Tags: oracle

```
select DISTINCT country, count(river)   
from geo_river
group by country
having count(river) > 3
INTERSECT
select DISTINCT country, count(province)
from geo_lake
group by lake,country
having count(province) > 3;
```

I'm sure USA is in it, but the result shows nothing, where is wrong?

I can't add pictures.
river_geo has river, country, province.
lake_geo has lake, country, province

"have lakes next to more than three provinces." means the lake has more than 3 province but these province belongs to the same country.

I want to find country that have this kind of lakes and have more than 3 rivers

Comment: You're looking for the set of countries that have (I'm inferring from your table names) the same number of rivers as lakes.  It seems unlikely that there would be many of those.  If you really want to look for countries that have more than 3 rivers and more than 3 lakes, you'd want to remove the `count(river)` and `count(province)` from your `select` lists.

Comment: I want to find country that have more than 3 rivers and have lakes which next to more than 3 provinces. but if I remove count, how to add this restriction?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your question to describe what you are trying to accomplish and to post some sample data and the expected results.  A reproducible test case (DDL, DML, expected results, etc.) would be ideal.  I'm not sure what you mean by "lakes with next to more than 3 provinces".  Do you mean that you want countries where there are more than 3 distinct province values in `geo_lake`?

Comment: my idea is find country have more than 3 rivers, and find country have this kind of lake, and then make intersection

Comment: I solved.this is the answer:

Comment: select DISTINCT country
from geo_river
group by country
having count(river) > 3
INTERSECT
select DISTINCT country
from geo_lake
group by lake,country
having count(province) > 3;